# Supported Android Devices shows 0 devices while uploading new APK to production

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I am trying to publish new version of my application and while uploading the APK I see `Supported Android devices`  as `0 devices`. I have only following `uses-permissions` in manifest file.

```
package="com.appname"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.2" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />



<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" >
</supports-screens>
```

[image]

there is no `uses-feature` in the manifest.

Comment: Please post the rest of your manifest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploaded APK to Play Store, got 0 supported devices but no error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978809/uploaded-apk-to-play-store-got-0-supported-devices-but-no-error)